# Class of monads in Dart

Tags: class, haskell, dart, monads

In Haskell, the definition of the class `Monad` is as follows:

```dart
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
  fail :: String -> m a
```

I want to express in Dart what the `m` in the above Haskell code says: every `Monad` class must have methods doing computations on objects of the same monad. Is it possible? How?

Comment: You think that DART is functional programming language? Do you know of examples in other languages? I think if exists example in other language (not functional) it can be easy adapted to Dart than direct analogy with Haskell example (from wikipedia).

Comment: I don't think Dart has interfaces (or similar) that allows for this type of expressive constraint; you may be able to accomplish this same thing but definitely not in the same expressive manner.

Answer (score 4):

`Future`is monadic, so you can look to it to see how this is done in Dart. The first thing to note is that Dart's type system isn't capable of fully typing all of the operations, but they still work basically the same.

`Future.then()` acts as bind (`>>=`).

If Dart had generic methods and union types, the Future interface might look like this:

```dart
Future<A> {
  Future<B> then<B>(Future<B>|B callback(A value));
}
```

(note: that's not real Dart!)

`then()` takes a callback function that takes an `A` and returns either a `Future<B>` or a `B`. If the callback returns a `B`, it's automatically converted into a `Future<B>`.

The equivalent to `>>` is to simply ignore the callback parameter.

If you don't do the automatic value to monad conversion, you can get a bit better typing, but due to the lack of generic methods, you can't be as precise as in Haskell. You might write it like this:

```dart
class Monad<A> {
  Monad/**<B>**/ bind(Monad/**<B>**/ callback(A value));
}
```